# How to pass multiple string values to single uniqueidentifier variable in sql?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have multiple string guid values and assigned that values to `@testVar`. When I tried to assign `@testVar`to `@testUnique` that time I am getting only one value.

How can I pass multiple guid values to single `uniqueidentifier`?

```
DECLARE @testVar VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @testUnique uniqueidentifier; 

set @testVar = ('66AF5627-4A6C-409B-8DB3-5062104BC70A' + ',' + '85FC0F5B-7A88-4743-BF8A-72DBD7BC4CE8');
print @testVar;
set @testUnique = @testVar;
print @testUnique;
```

For example:

```
print @testVar;
```

Output :

```
66AF5627-4A6C-409B-8DB3-5062104BC70A,85FC0F5B-7A88-4743-BF8A-72DBD7BC4CE8
```

Example:

```
print @testUnique;
```

Output :

```
66AF5627-4A6C-409B-8DB3-5062104BC70A
```

I need output like:

```
66AF5627-4A6C-409B-8DB3-5062104BC70A,85FC0F5B-7A88-4743-BF8A-72DBD7BC4CE8
```

Comment: It's a **single** `uniqueidentifier` variable, so it can hold **at most ONE** value. If you need multiple values, look at table variables